# Sql injection get id solution

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know how to make this code safe. I tried to use mysql_real_escape_string in the query variable like

```html
$query = "select * from products where id= " . mysql_real_escape_string($products);
```

but didn't work, also tried to escape in the products variable, but got the same result.
Any sugestions?
Thanks.

```html
<?php

/ Define vars.
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test');
$products = isset($_GET["products"]) ? $_GET["products"] : "";
$query = "select * from products where id=$products";

// List elements.
if ($conn)
{
 mysql_select_db('testsqli');
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 
 // Table head.
 echo '<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">';
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>Description</td>';
 echo '<td>Price</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
 
 // Empty table?
 if (@mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
 {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td><i>That\'s all!</i></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
 }
  // Listing data in table.
  while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo '<td>'.$row['Description'].'</td>';;
   echo '<td>'.$row['Price'].'</td>';;
   
  }
 echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Define: *didn't work*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's still vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: either use mysqli or pdo - with prepared statements and bound parameters

Comment: ^ that helps, but let's not leave XSS out of the picture. Prepared statements aren't a 100% solution.

Comment: @RamRaider I agree with that, but I still want to do this in a old way

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection <= read that and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to add quotes, (and use msqli instead) like:

```php
$query = "select * from products where id='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($products)."'";

// or

$query = sprintf(
  "select * from products where id='%s'",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($products)
);
```

Comment: yes, it was so easy. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of MySQL escaping. Escaping skips over some of the wildcards, such as '%' and '*' which could also provide unanticipated results.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID=?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $products, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();
```

Also, keep in mind the following measures keep it safe:

- Never connect to the database as a superuser or as the database owner. Use always customized users with very limited privileges.
- Check if the given input has the expected data type. (In this case, verify that $products is formatted as expected, i.e. if your product catalog has indices of only nine characters, make sure it's not 100 characters long.) PHP has a wide range of input validating functions, from the simplest ones found in Variable Functions and in Character Type Functions (e.g. is_numeric(), ctype_digit() respectively) and onwards to the Perl compatible Regular Expressions support.
- If the application waits for numerical input, consider verifying data with ctype_digit(), or silently change its type using settype(), or use its numeric representation by sprintf().

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php